# css disappears on the click of a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I got a countdown timer that starts working on click of a button. i tried to apply css to it, but when i click on the start button the css disappears. can anyone tell how i can retain my css the whole time

here is my code @[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/learner001/ecq9f1bL/)

```js
 $('#startClock').click(function() {
   var counter = 120;
   setInterval(function() {
     counter--;
     if (counter >= 0) {
       span = document.getElementById("count");
       var str = parseInt(counter / 60) + ':' + (counter % 60);
       span.innerHTML = str;
     }
     if (counter === 0) {
       alert('sorry, out of time');
       clearInterval(counter);
     }
   }, 1000);

 });
```

```css
.first_digit {
  width: 60px;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding: 4px;
  color: #CCC;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 2px #000;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #333;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
.second_digit {
  color: #333;
  font-size: 40px;
}
.third_digit {
  width: 60px;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding: 4px;
  color: #CCC;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 2px #000;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #333;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
.fourth_digit {
  width: 60px;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding: 4px;
  color: #CCC;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 2px #000;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #333;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="count">
        <span class="first_digit">2</span>
<span class="second_digit">:</span>
<span class="third_digit">0</span>
<span class="fourth_digit">0</span>
</span>

<button class="rightbtn" type="button" id="startClock">Start</button>
```

Comment: you are replacing all the spans you styled.

Comment: `span.innerHTML = str` This is actually breaking your `CSS`

Comment: @Tushar Raj can u plz tell me how i can correct my code

Comment: @Gerald Schneider how can i correct it

Comment: @kavi [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ecq9f1bL/9/)

Comment: @kavi See my answer and fiddle . It works .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ecq9f1bL/12/):

You just need to modify this line

```
span.innerHTML = str;
```

to

```
span.innerHTML = '<span class="first_digit">' + parseInt(counter / 60) + '</span><span class="second_digit">:</span><span class="third_digit">' + parseInt((counter % 60) / 10) + '</span> <span class="fourth_digit">' + (counter % 60) % 10;
```

Comment: thanks, can u plz tell me one more thing, if i wish to reset the counter to its initial value how can i do so??

Comment: See my updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ecq9f1bL/13/ . It solves your problem but you need to check the intervals . As every next time , the interval is being decreased . So the values are being decremented bit fast . If you unable to get this work out, then i will help .

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('#startClock').click(function(){
    var counter = 120;
  setInterval(function() {
    counter--;
    if (counter >= 0) {
        $("#count span:eq(0)").text(parseInt(counter / 60));
        $("#count span:eq(2)").text((counter % 60).toString().split("")[0]);
        $("#count span:eq(3)").text((counter % 60).toString().split("")[1]);
    }
    if (counter === 0) {
        alert('sorry, out of time');
        clearInterval(counter);
    }
  }, 1000);

});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ecq9f1bL/8/)

Comment: check the time in between 1:00 to 1:10 mins it went wrong

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in your if-condition:

```
if (counter >= 0) {
  span = document.getElementById("count");
    var str = parseInt(counter / 60) + ':' + (counter % 60);
  span.innerHTML = str;
}
```

The last line inserts the value of the variable `str` to the main span tag with id `count`.

The previous content, all the span tags, is replaced.

EDIT:

You have to call the single span tags, not the main span tag:

```
if (counter >= 0) {
    span1 = document.getElementById("first-digit");
    span3 = document.getElementById("third-digit");
    span4 = document.getElementById("fourth-digit");
    span1.innerHTML = parseInt(counter / 60);
    span3.innerHTML = String(counter % 60)[0];
    span4.innerHTML = String(counter % 60)[1];
}
```

And add the IDs to your span tags:

```
<div id="count">
    <span id="first-digit" class="first_digit">2</span>
    <span id="second-digit" class="second_digit">:</span>
    <span id="third-digit" class="third_digit">0</span>
    <span id="fourth-digit" class="fourth_digit">0</span>
</div>
```

I made div tag out of your main span tag.

Answer (score 0):

On those lines :

```
span = document.getElementById("count");
var str = parseInt(counter / 60) + ':' + (counter % 60);
span.innerHTML = str;
```

You rewrite the content of your `count` div, so that :

```
<span class="first_digit">2</span>
<span class="second_digit">:</span>
<span class="third_digit">0</span>
<span class="fourth_digit">0</span>
```

become this after the first interval :

```
1:59
```

What you may want to do is to break down your "time" into individualt char and assign them directly into `first_digit`, `second_digit`, etc

Comment: i am a bit new to it, can u plz tell how can i recode it to achieve my target

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there is a much more elegant way to do this, however this should work.

The issue is essentially when replacing the inner HTML, all the elements (namely the spans) are removed and replaced with a simple string.

```
$('#startClock').click(function(){
    var counter = 120;
  setInterval(function() {
    counter--;
    if (counter >= 0) {
      span = document.getElementById("count");
        var minutes = parseInt(counter / 60);
        var seconds = parseInt(counter % 60);
        var secondstens = Math.floor(seconds / 10);
        var secondsones = seconds % 10;

        var str = '<span class="first_digit">' + minutes + '</span>' + '<span class="second_digit">:</span><span class="third_digit">' + secondstens + '</span><span class="fourth_digit">' + secondsones + '</span>'

      span.innerHTML = str;
    }
    if (counter === 0) {
        alert('sorry, out of time');
        clearInterval(counter);
    }
  }, 1000);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You just need to add class to your element

```
        $(".first_digit").html(str.split(':')[0]);

        $(".third_digit").html(str.split(':')[1].toString()[0]);
        $(".fourth_digit").html(str.split(':')[1].toString()[1]);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ecq9f1bL/15/

Comment: thanks it seems to work but brings all the digits together, is there a way where i can keep each digit seperately